# manipulating a dom element without modifying the actual dom state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that when we do this:

```
var el = $("#el")
```

We're essentially taking a reference to an actual DOM element. And doing `$("#el").text("new text")` will result the text on this element (in the DOM) to be changed.

My question is, what if I wanted to use this element as a template?

```
var new_element = $("#el").text("new element") // just this element manipulation
$("ul").prepend( new_element ); // actual dom manipulation
```

Or, do I have to inject the `<div id="newObject"></div>` into the DOM world, take it's reference and then manipulate?

EDIT:

$("#el").clone() is the way to do that

Comment: `var $new_element = $("#el").clone(); $new_element.text("new element");`

Comment: @mplungjan yup `clone` it is. thanks mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not need to put it into the DOM. You can just have jQuery create the element and reference it. It is important you clone the element. If you do not it will just alter the original one and since an element can not be in two places at once it will just move.

```js
const templateLi = $('<li class="foo"></li>')

function addLi(text) {
  const li = templateLi.clone().text(text)
  $("ul").append(li)
}

addLi("hello")
addLi("bacon")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

</ul>
```

Comment: Hmm. Really worth an answer? See my comment under the question

Comment: Really worth the comment? ;)